# What is the difference between int* p and int** p in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, variables, integer

I just learn about pointer in C++ and I'm confused with the usage of pointer when it comes to int* (with 1 asterisk) and int** (with 2 asterisk). Can anyone explain why I should use both of them and the usage?

Comment: That's a [double pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-pointer-pointer-pointer-c/).

Comment: `int i` declares `i` as a variable of type `int` (i.e. its value is integral).   `int *p` declares `p` as a variable who's value is the address of an `int`.  `p` can be assigned a value which is the address of  an `int`, such as `p = &i`.     `int **p2` declares `p2` as a variable who's value is the address of an `int *`.  Similarly `p2` can be store the address of an `int *`, such as `p2  = &p`.